# Converting string to is0-8859-1, saving to database as base64, but when decoded comes out as utf8

Tags: perl, utf-8

I'm really confused with this one! So here is what is happening. I'm using `MIME::Base64` to encrypt a hashref into a string, using:

```
encode_base64(JSON::XS->new->latin1->encode($vars))
```

One of the variables in `$vars` is called `comment` ... so `$vars->{comment}`

When I get the text out of the database, the contents are:

```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```

Doing a **Devel::Peek::Dump** on the base64 coming out, the flag look perfect:

```
SV = PV(0x2e419b8) at 0x1eece38
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2eeaf70 "eyJwaG9uZSI6InNkZnNkZnNmZCIsImNvbW1lbnRzIjoi7fPpIHRlc3QgYWNjZW50cyB4eHh4eCIs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\nIn0=\n"\0
  CUR = 775
  LEN = 776
```

I am then decoding it with:

```
my $vars = JSON::XS->new->latin1->decode(decode_base64($base64));
```

However, upon decoding it if I do:

```
Dump($vars->{comments});
```

I get this in the `Dump()` ;

```
SV = PV(0x31c06b8) at 0x2f4f208
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x32635f0 "\303\255\303\263\303\251 test accents xxxxx"\0 [UTF8 "\x{ed}\x{f3}\x{e9} test accents xxxxx"]
  CUR = 25
  LEN = 32
```

As you can see, it has the UTF8 flag still. I'm stumped as to why it would be doing this.

Has anyone got some ideas on what I can try?

**UPDATE:**  As suggested, I have done a dump before encoding, and after decoding (right away, skipping the database). As suggested, it looks like it **is** converting it into utf8 :/

```
BEFORE ENCODING:

SV = PVMG(0x2a19a40) at 0x2a66588
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x2320af0 "\355\363\351 test accents xxxxx"\0
  CUR = 22
  LEN = 24

AFTER DECODING STRAIGHT AFTER:
SV = PV(0x2a64b08) at 0x2a6b730
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x2ab2200 "\303\255\303\263\303\251 test accents xxxxx"\0 [UTF8 "\x{ed}\x{f3}\x{e9} test accents xxxxx"]
  CUR = 25
  LEN = 32
```

Any ideas on what I can do to stop it doing that?

**UPDATE 2:**

The data coming in comes from a jQuery `$.ajax()` request, and thus in *utf8* format. So what I'm doing is converting it to *iso-8859-1* format:

```
$in->{$_} = Unicode::MapUTF8::from_utf8({-string => $in->{$_}, -charset => 'ISO-8859-1'});
```

Unfortunatly all the website and database are in iso-8859-1 format, so I can't use UTF8 for any of the data (which is why I'm converting)

Comment: Is the base64 that goes into the DB the same? What DB are you using? What data type does the field have? What does the `Dump` look like if you un-json it immediately after you converted it, skipping the database entirely.

Comment: Also, what does the `Dump` on the data look like before you `encode_base64` it? [The JSON::XS docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS#latin1-or-ascii-flags-enabled) say _With latin1 (or ascii) enabled, encode will escape characters with ordinal values > 255 (> 127 with ascii) and encode the remaining characters as specified by the utf8 flag._. That might be the case here.

Comment: @simbabque thanks for the replies. I've updated my opening question with those tests. It seems like it does encode is turning it into utf8, even when I explicitly tell it not to. I wonder if there is a work around?

Comment: Is it already utf8 when it goes in? It seems like you expect it to downgrade it to latin1, but that's not what JSON::XS is supposed to do. You'd have to do that with Encode first. You can see that the characters are from above the ASCII (latin1) range in your _before_ output and your _after_ output. Before, they are Perl's character representation, they are high, and there are only three. Afterwards they have been encoded as utf8, so now they are are two bytes, but represented individually. If you want to convert your French accented letters to their latin1 representation, use Encode.

Comment: @simbabque It's sent via jQuery's $.ajax request, so in utf8 format, and then I decode it in the perl script as `$in->{$_} = Unicode::MapUTF8::from_utf8({-string => $in->{$_}, -charset => 'ISO-8859-1'});`.  .. that should be the correct way to do it, no? I would love to just convfert the whole site to use utf8 (even the DB), but its a beast of a site and is setup with iso-8859-1 encoding in both the DB and pages.

Comment: That's the most crucial part of the question. [Edit] it in!

Comment: @simbabque sorry - added in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136740/discussion-between-simbabque-and-andrew-newby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON::XS is doing some encoding on the data, as it wants stuff to be in utf8. If you do not need the JSON, but you only want to persist the data to retrieve it later, you can just use a different way of serializing that doesn't mess with your encoding.

The [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) module, which comes with core Perl, lets you convert Perl data structures to a binary representation that you can save in your database. A BLOB field would make sense.

```
use Storable;

my $binary = freeze($data_structure);

# somewhere else...

my $data_structure = thaw($binary)
```

Comment: Thanks - and thanks for taking the time to work that through with me. I was losing my hair!